# Cannot see other computers in network anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I recently had to do an update on my Windows 7 Laptop. Before the update, I was able to see all of the computers that are connected to my network, but now I only see my own computer. I've opened the network control panel and checked, but the settings haven't changed.

How can I get to see the other computers again? (Yes, network detection etc. is all enabled.)

Comment: Are ou set to run on a homegroup? Windows file sharing seems to have issues when homegroup is managing your shares.

Comment: You need to have more details about the computer you're using, company/model.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your not in the same workgroup anymore.

1. Right click my computer and go to properties (or System from control
   panel)
2. Click change settings on the lower right.
3. Then change/verify workgroup on your laptop as well as the other computers.

[image: Change workgroup]

If you are not in the same workgroup you are, in the eyes of a windows computer, not on the same network for share access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the problem by installing [WirelessNetView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_view.html).
If it's work well, Then you could know if is the OS causing the problem or some driver.
You can also do a System Restore if it does not work for you, and check which update is causing the problem.